# running script through all open worksheets

Tags: excel, loops, charts, vba

I have looked through 4 other loop through all open sheets in a excel book, all found searching on stackoverflow. I am very new to VBA so I am having difficulties understanding how to manipulate those answers into my code.

What I would like to do is create a chart in every active worksheet. Below is my code for creating a chart in Sheet 1 (found from another post and changed parameters to what I needed). It creates the chart exactly how I would like it. I do not know how to reference the current sheet in my code instead of Sheet 1, so I know that is my first hurdle. I did find how to loop on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/142126 but it only runs for Sheet 1 since I do not know how to correctly change that parameter.

```
Sub chartcreation()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart

    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    With chrt
        'Data?
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet1!B1"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Sheet1!$A$3:$A$630"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$630"

        'Titles
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "=Sheet1!B1"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Range("A2")
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Range("B2")

        'Formatting
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 15
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 90
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 60
        .HasLegend = True

    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: What is an active worksheet per your definition? You can only have 1 active worksheet at a time.

Comment: And do you have your data in Sheet1?

Comment: Sorry that I am unclear. I will have 384 sheets in one file that I would like to loop through. So each sheet contains that data in columns A and B that I want to create a chart from. If I change my script to each sheet number, I know that would work, but I was wondering if a loop would be simpler so I do not have the 384 copies of the above script.

Comment: Just remember to add all the information needed another time ;-) The answer has already been giving, was a very easy change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is setup pretty well and only requires a few changes.  First loop through all worksheets in ActiveWorkbook and then change the values to reference the sheet variable.

```
Sub chartcreation()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

        With chrt
            'Data?
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = sh.Range("B1").Value
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = sh.Range("$A$3:$A$630")
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = sh.Range("$B$3:$B$630")

            'Titles
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = sh.Range("B1").Value
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = sh.Range("A2")
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = sh.Range("B2")

            'Formatting
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
            .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 15
            .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 90
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 60
            .HasLegend = True
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Tested**

[image]

Comment: Using `sh.Range("B1").Value` will make those values static, based on what was in the cell at the time the chart was created.  You will need to write those as formulae, e.g. `... = "='" & sh.Name & "'!B1"` in order to preserve the existing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the Sheets by using

```
Sheets("Sheetname").Select
```

there you can just put the name of the sheet into the brickets.
Or you can use this:

```
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

this gives you the number of workbooks out. and by .Select you can select one after the other

Comment: How is that a loop?